# CSS div children same width and bigger than page window size

Tags: html, width, css

Everyone this is my first post, so I hope I did it right.

I am facing a problem where I have child divs that need to be the same width. The `#content` can be bigger than the browser window (hence the `3000px`, but won't always be bigger than the browser window). Currently `#content` is shown properly and I can use the scrollbar to see the entire `#content`, but `#messages` and `#menu` are cut off at the width of the browser window.

I have tried using `width: inherit` and several other options, but they didn't work. Does anyone else have a working solution?

I have created a JSFiddle to make life easier http://jsfiddle.net/Ks665/ 
I have added a screenshot of the probleem:

[image]

The red and green must become as long as the blue div.

**HTML:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" media="screen"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="messages">test</div>
    <div id="menu">test</div>
    <div id="content">test</div>    
</body>
<html>
```

**CSS:**

```
@import url('reset.css');

body {
    min-width: 990px;
}

#messages {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}

#menu {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}

#content {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 250px;
    width: 3000px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try wrapping them inside another DIV, and specify the width on there; the child DIVs will automatically fill to the width of the parent:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="messages">test</div>
    <div id="menu">test</div>
    <div id="content">test</div>
</div>
```

And then apply the width to the container DIV instead of to 'content':

```
#container {
    width: 3000px;
}
```

The reason it isn't working in your example is because the DIVs are children of the body tag, which has a minimum width specified, but nothing explicitly defined like I've shown above.

Comment: Hmm, I'm having difficulty making that work, don't think CSS is designed that way. The best I can come up with is to add this:

`#content {
    ...
    overflow-x: scroll;
}`